# Text scales in Threejs - GridHelper

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I modified the GridHelper file to permit different size of axis X and Y. Now I can create rectangles as grid. 
I'm interested in add text scales without reduce the performance in creating a lot of text.

Thanks for the ideas !

```
THREE.GridHelper = function ( sizeX, sizeY, step) {

var x = Math.round(sizeX/step);
var y = Math.round(sizeY/step);

sizeX = x*step;
sizeY = y*step;

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

this.color1 = new THREE.Color( 0x444444 );
this.color2 = new THREE.Color( 0x888888 );

for ( var i = 0; i <= sizeX; i += step ) {

    geometry.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3( i, 0, 0 ), 
        new THREE.Vector3( i, 0, sizeY )
    );

    var color = i === 0 ? this.color1 : this.color2;

    geometry.colors.push( color, color, color, color );

}

for ( var i = 0; i <= sizeY; i += step ) {

    geometry.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, i ), 
        new THREE.Vector3( sizeX, 0, i )
    );

    var color = i === 0 ? this.color1 : this.color2;

    geometry.colors.push( color, color, color, color );

}

THREE.Line.call( this, geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces );
};

THREE.GridHelper.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Line.prototype );

THREE.GridHelper.prototype.setColors = function( colorCenterLine, colorGrid ) {

this.color1.set( colorCenterLine );
this.color2.set( colorGrid );

this.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```